# Wrong jQuery event firing from mobile devices

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm having issues from mobile devices with the following div, link and jQuery:

```
<div id="div1" style="width:300px;height:100px;">
    <a href="#" id="link1">Link</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#link1').click(function() {
    alert('Clicked link');
});  

$('#div1').mouseenter(function(){
    alert('Entered div');
});  
</script>
```

From a PC if you hover div1, it alerts "Entered div".  When you click link1, it alerts "Clicked link".  Perfect.

However, from a mobile device hover does not work. Which is okay, but when a user clicks link1, it alerts "Entered div" first.  If they click again it alerts "Clicked link".

How can I get it to alert "Clicked link" the first time a user clicks link1 from a mobile device without sacrificing how it works from a desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to mobile devices :)

You need to feature-detect if you are running on a touch-enabled device and either not bind your mouseenter events, or bind to the touch events directly and prevent them from getting converted into clicks and mouseenters.

Answer (score 0):

can you give a try as below,

if you say return false , it can stop the propagation , but i am not 100% sure with mobile devices..just give a try

```
$('#link1').click(function() {
    alert('Clicked link');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I've just implemented the following...

```
var is_ios = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);

if(!is_ios){ 

  // bind my hover behaviours here

}
```

add an `else` to that if you want to do something specifically for iphone/ipad/ipod.  In my case I didn't need to.